# Trigger for checking two items in different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

For this, i have this tables (Usuario, compra and tarjeta_credito) and the nested table Pago.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Usuario_ObjTyp AS OBJECT (
id_usuario NUMBER(8),
nick VARCHAR2(20),
nombre VARCHAR(20),
apellido VARCHAR(20),
email VARCHAR(30),
contrasena VARCHAR(30),
ct_amigos NUMBER(4),
direccion VARCHAR2(30),
localidad VARCHAR2(20),
cp VARCHAR2(7),
pais VARCHAR2(20),
telefono VARCHAR2(10),
Tarjetas REF Tarjeta_Credito_ObjTyp,
PayPal_Usuario REF Paypal_ObjTyp,
 MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Get_Nick RETURN VARCHAR2
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Tarjeta_Credito_ObjTyp AS OBJECT(
id_tarjeta NUMBER(8),
num_tarjeta VARCHAR2(30),
fecha_caducidad DATE,
ccv NUMBER(3),
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Get_numTarjeta RETURN VARCHAR2
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Pago_ObjTyp AS OBJECT(
cod_pago NUMBER(8),
cantidad_pago NUMBER(5,2),
fecha_pago DATE,
Tarjeta_Credito REF Tarjeta_Credito_ObjTyp,
Paypal REF Paypal_ObjTyp,

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Pago_ObjTyp
(SELF IN OUT NOCOPY Pago_ObjTyp, cod_pago NUMBER,
cantidad_pago NUMBER, fecha_pago DATE, Tarjeta_Credito
Tarjeta_Credito_ObjTyp, PayPal Paypal_ObjTyp)
RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE pago_ntabtyp AS TABLE OF Pago_ObjTyp;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Compra_ObjTyp AS OBJECT (
num_compra NUMBER(8),
fecha_compra DATE,
precio_totalc NUMBER(5,2),
lineasCompra Linea_Compra_ntabtyp,
Usuario REF Usuario_ObjTyp,
pagoCompra pago_ntabtyp,
MAP MEMBER FUNCTION Get_numcompra RETURN NUMBER
);
```

What I want to do is to check that the user (Usuario) is not using another credit card (Tarjeta_Credito) that is not from him. For example, if I have an user with id_tarjeta 1, it needs to check that when I insert a purchase (Compra) and pays(Pago), the credit card is the same used that the user has associated (id_tarjeta = 1) and goes for an error if it's not 1 (In this example).
Also, an Usuario only can have one credit card, so it doesn't need a loop to check the credit cards.

What I have in the moment is this: (It's not correct)

```
create or replace TRIGGER Act_CompraTarjeta
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Compra_OBJTAB
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        VUSER COMPRA.USUARIO%TYPE;
        VPAGO COMPRA.PAGOCOMPRA%TYPE;
  
    BEGIN
        --COMPROBAMOS SI EL ID DE LA TARJETA DE COMPRA(PAGO) ES IGUAL AL DEL USUARIO
          --SACO EL NUMERO DE TARJETA DEL USUARIO AL QUE QUEREMOS AÑADIR UNA COMPRA
        SELECT T.ID_TARJETA INTO VUSER FROM TARJETA_CREDITO_OBJTAB T WHERE REF(T) IN (
                SELECT U.TARJETAS FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB U WHERE ID_USUARIO = :NEW.ID_USUARIO);
        --SACAMOS EL NUMERO DE TARJETA DE PAGO (PARA COMPROBARLO CON EL DEL USUARIO)
       SELECT T.TARJETA_CREDITO INTO VPAGO FROM PAGO_OBJTYP T WHERE REF(T) IN(
                SELECT T.ID_TARJETA FROM TARJETA_CREDITO_OBJTAB T WHERE REF(T) IN (
                    SELECT U.TARJETAS FROM USUARIO_OBJTAB U WHERE ID_USUARIO = :NEW.ID_USUARIO));
                    
        IF :NEW.PagoCompra IS NOT NULL THEN
               IF VPAGO != VUSER THEN
                raise_application_error(-20000, 'No coinciden las tarjetas');
                END IF;

        end if;
        if inserting then
               INSERT INTO compra_objtab c
                    VALUES (:NEW.num_compra, :NEW.fecha_compra, :NEW.precio_totalc, :NEW.lineasCompra, :NEW.USUARIO, :NEW.PAGOCOMPRA);
               --RETURNING REF(c) into VUSER;
        end if;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE COMPRA_OBJTAB SET num_compra = :NEW.num_compra, fecha_compra = :NEW.fecha_compra, precio_totalc = :NEW.PRECIO_TOTALC, lineasCompra = :NEW.lineasCompra, 
            Usuario = :NEW.Usuario, PagoCompra = :NEW.PagoCompra
            WHERE num_compra = :OLD.num_compra;
        END IF;
END;
```

I tried to make variables so I can compare the id of the user (Usuario) with the credit card (tarjeta_credito), but i think im just so confused right know, and I don't know how to continue.

**EDIT AND ACTUAL**: i tried this, but still doesnt work out, any help pls?
´´´
create or replace TRIGGER Act_CompraTarjeta
before INSERT OR UPDATE ON Compra_objtab
FOR EACH ROW

```
BEGIN    
    IF ((:NEW.PagoCompra).tarjeta_credito) IS NOT NULL THEN
           IF ( (deref(:new.usuario).tarjetas)= ((:new.pagocompra).tarjeta_credito)) THEN
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'No coinciden las tarjetas');
            END IF;
END IF;

    IF UPDATING THEN
        UPDATE COMPRA_OBJTAB SET num_compra = :NEW.num_compra, fecha_compra = :NEW.fecha_compra, precio_totalc = :NEW.PRECIO_TOTALC, lineasCompra = :NEW.lineasCompra, 
        Usuario = :NEW.Usuario, PagoCompra = :NEW.PagoCompra
        WHERE num_compra = :OLD.num_compra;
    END IF;
```

END;

Comment: I would not recommend you to do this through trigger. You may create a separate stored procedure that has the logic that you're planning to have inside trigger. You may then call this SP first; if all's good, you may continue with your normal flow, else show the necessary validation to the end-user.

Comment: Oh, I see, maybe that way will be easier. Thank you so much!